# I am getting a warning for the website deployed via Github pages that uses a custom domain. how do i get around it?

Tags: github, deployment

Problem:

- I am getting below warning on github pages. However, my custom domain http://www.dilipagheda.com still works.
- I am curious why i am getting this warning and do i need to address it? if yes, how?

Error:

```
The custom domain for your GitHub Pages site is pointed at an outdated IP address. You must update your site's DNS records if you'd like it to be available via your custom domain
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure why it still works (maybe they're phasing people out to the new addresses?) but here's how to fix it.

Go to your domain registrar, where you have previously set up your DNS records.  You need to update your A records to the new ones provided by github.  Right now they are:

```
185.199.108.153
185.199.109.153
185.199.110.153
185.199.111.153
```

After that, you need to delete and re-add your custom domain in the repo settings.  I got these IP addresses and instructions [here](https://help.github.com/en/articles/setting-up-an-apex-domain#configuring-a-records-with-your-dns-provider) in the github documentation.